# VIM Deleting ^B and previous characters

Tags: regex, vim

Example

```
Ë^_I^BTest: 717121 -- V3K AD 1 Chan 1 CALBYPASS relays test
```

I want to delete the ^B and all character to the beginning of the line.

Comment: probably he meant Beginning of Line :) Expected output would help.

Answer (score 2):

vim fundamentally treats Control-B like any other character; it's just slightly more difficult to enter it (you have to type<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd>), and it's displayed as `^B` rather than as itself (since it's a non-printable character).

In a regular expression, `^` matches the beginning of the line, and `.*` matches any number of arbitrary characters. So, assuming you're on the line containing the ^B, type:

```
:s/^.*^B//
```

where for `^B` you need to type <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd>.

This will change the line from:

```
Ë^_I^BTest: 717121 -- V3K AD 1 Chan 1 CALBYPASS relays test
```

to:

```
Test: 717121 -- V3K AD 1 Chan 1 CALBYPASS relays test
```